# Mapping an Optional Seq

Tags: scala

I have read a few posts about how to handle a `Seq[Option[x], Option[x]]` but I have a different situation, I have an `Option[Seq[x]]`. I'm struggling to map this, what I want is something like:

```
val x: Option[Seq[String]] = ...
x.map((y: String) => ...)
```

instead I get `x.map((y: Seq[String] =>)`

Of course I can handle this using for comprehension and maybe that's the correct approach but I'd appreciate any advice about how to handle this

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Honestly I can't select the "correct" answer because all the options seem valid, but the answers are very educational and I hope they're useful to others

Comment: With all these functions on `Option` in the solutions, [Tony Morris' `Option` cheat sheet](http://tonymorris.github.io/blog/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/) might help.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'll take a look

Answer (score 1):

You could use `getOrElse` to `map` on the actual `Seq`.

```
x.getOrElse(Nil).map((y:String) => ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Option` also supports the `fold` operation:

```
x.fold(Seq[String]())((entry) => entry).map( ... )
```

I think marteljn's solution is more readable, though.

Answer (score 1):

Or simply:

```
x.map(_.map(y: String => ... ))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are, as almost always, several ways:

```
x.toSeq.flatten.map(string: String => ???)


x.toSeq.flatMap(_.map(string => ???))
```

and my personal favorite:

```
x.fold(Seq.empty[String])(_.map(string => ???))
```

Comment: In your last solution `string` is a `Seq[String]`.